# Hacer registros en un Data Grid View con valores nulos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Estoy trabajando en un data grid view en el cual al realizar doble click me tiene que abrir un formulario para editar con los datos del registro del datagridview, el problema surge al momento de terminar la edicion me marca error porque dejo valores en ciertos campos pero asi es necesario, como puedo dejar valores nulos en un datagridview? trabajo en c# Abajo el codigo

```
        frmEditar Editar = new frmEditar();

        Editar.txtSalesOrderE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        Editar.cmbCustomerE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtTotalE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtTotalTicketE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        Editar.cmbModelE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtDateReceveidE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

        Editar.Show();
```